# convert string to float inside a SUMIF function

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm using the SUMIF function except that the column I'm trying to sum is a string like this: "AU $12.3" instead of just "12", how can I strip this string to just return the float value inside my SUMIF statement (in the E column)?

```
=SUMIF('may'!$D$1:$D$500,"*Amount*",'may'!$E$1:$E$500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Amount",May!$D$1:$D$500))*REPLACE(May!$E$1:$E$500,1,4,0))
```

Comment: cool, this returns 0 for a strange reason, so I`ve tried the REPLACE by itself it works fine, any way to put in back in the SUMIF function instead ?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting 0, can you post a larger sample? SUMIF only allows ranges as arguments, you need to use SUMPRODUCT to work with arrays.

Comment: I note google-spreadsheet tag. lori_m's formula will give you zero in google spreadsheet, try this version `=ArrayFormula(SUM(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Amount",May!$D$1:$D$500))*REPLACE(May!$E$1:$E$500,1,4,0)))`

Comment: yes, this is a google spreadsheet one, thanks for pointing that out . The ArrayFormula is returning a parse error unfortunately, what would a parse error indicate ?